# Linux HTB number of levels

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping, tc

Re-modified [Linux HTB](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-tc-htb/) by adding a single printk message in [htb_dequeue](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/sched/sch_htb.c#L936) function.

```
static struct sk_buff *htb_dequeue(struct Qdisc *sch)
{
    ... original code
    ... original code
    for (level = 0; level < TC_HTB_MAXDEPTH; level++) {
        printk("Current level in loop is: %d\n", level);
        ... original code
    }
}
```

In the official documentation it says:

> Each class is assigned level. Leaf has ALWAYS level 0 and root
>   classes have level TC_HTB_MAXDEPTH-1. Interior nodes has level
>   one less than their parent.

I've run the following example:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100kbps ceil 100kbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 40kbps ceil 100kbps
```

---

```
             root
               |
               |
             class rate 100kbps ceil 100kbps
               |
             Leaf  rate 40kbps ceil 100kbps
```

The height should be 2 or 3, no more than 3

However after I run this, I inspect the output in dmesg I get the following:

```
Current level in loop is: 0
Current level in loop is: 1
Current level in loop is: 2
Current level in loop is: 3
Current level in loop is: 4
Current level in loop is: 5
Current level in loop is: 6
Current level in loop is: 7
```

I had no idea why this output, so I ran it again with the following diagram

```
             root
               |
               |
             class rate 100kbps ceil 100kbps
               |
             class rate 70kbps ceil 100kbps
               |
             Leaf rate 40kbps ceil 100kbps
```

And I had the same output in dmesg...

I made sure I compiled the kernel correctly after adding the printk

```
make
make modules_install
make install
update-initramfs -c -k 4.17.0+
update-grub
```

restarted machine and the kernel was updated as I had the output of the printk.

My question is: why the height is 7 and not 2 ?